# Moving Python & Javascript code to Raspberry Pi created INTERNAL SERVER ERROR with Twilio Video Streaming Demo

Tags: javascript, python, twilio, video-streaming

I setup a Twilio video streaming tutorial using a [walkthrough part 1](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/get-started-with-twilio-video-node-express-server.) and [part 2](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/get-started-with-twilio-video-python-flask-frontend) which works great on my Macbook.  I then moved the code to a Raspberry PI and I'm not able to get it to work.  After troubleshooting various library issues, the server now runs.

The problem is the video doesn't load.  Specifically in the browser console I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

and in the Terminal I see the error:

```
main.js:14 POST http://localhost:5002/join-room 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
startRoom @ main.js:14
VM17:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

The Python code is:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const AccessToken = require("twilio").jwt.AccessToken;
const VideoGrant = AccessToken.VideoGrant;
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 5002;

// use the Express JSON middleware
app.use(express.json());

// create the twilioClient
const twilioClient = require("twilio")(
  process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SID,
  process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET,
  { accountSid: process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID }
);

const findOrCreateRoom = async (roomName) => {
  try {
    // see if the room exists already. If it doesn't, this will throw
    // error 20404.
    await twilioClient.video.rooms(roomName).fetch();
  } catch (error) {
    // the room was not found, so create it
    if (error.code == 20404) {
      await twilioClient.video.rooms.create({
        uniqueName: roomName,
        type: "go",
      });
    } else {
      // let other errors bubble up
      throw error;
    }
  }
};

const getAccessToken = (roomName) => {
  // create an access token
  const token = new AccessToken(
    process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
    process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SID,
    process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET,
    // generate a random unique identity for this participant
    { identity: uuidv4() }
  );
  // create a video grant for this specific room
  const videoGrant = new VideoGrant({
    room: roomName,
  });

  // add the video grant
  token.addGrant(videoGrant);
  // serialize the token and return it
  return token.toJwt();
};

app.post("/join-room", async (req, res) => {
  // return 400 if the request has an empty body or no roomName
  if (!req.body || !req.body.roomName) {
    return res.status(400).send("Must include roomName argument.");
  }
  const roomName = req.body.roomName;
  // find or create a room with the given roomName
  findOrCreateRoom(roomName);
  // generate an Access Token for a participant in this room
  const token = getAccessToken(roomName);
  res.send({
    token: token,
  });
});

// Start the Express server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Express server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

The Javascript Frontend code is:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const AccessToken = require("twilio").jwt.AccessToken;
const VideoGrant = AccessToken.VideoGrant;
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

// use the Express JSON middleware
app.use(express.json());

// create the twilioClient
const twilioClient = require("twilio")(
  process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SID,
  process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET,
  { accountSid: process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID }
);

const findOrCreateRoom = async (roomName) => {
  try {
    // see if the room exists already. If it doesn't, this will throw
    // error 20404.
    await twilioClient.video.rooms(roomName).fetch();
  } catch (error) {
    // the room was not found, so create it
    if (error.code == 20404) {
      await twilioClient.video.rooms.create({
        uniqueName: roomName,
        type: "go",
      });
    } else {
      // let other errors bubble up
      throw error;
    }
  }
};

const getAccessToken = (roomName) => {
  // create an access token
  const token = new AccessToken(
    process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
    process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SID,
    process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET,
    // generate a random unique identity for this participant
    { identity: uuidv4() }
  );
  // create a video grant for this specific room
  const videoGrant = new VideoGrant({
    room: roomName,
  });

  // add the video grant
  token.addGrant(videoGrant);
  // serialize the token and return it
  return token.toJwt();
};

app.post("/join-room", async (req, res) => {
  // return 400 if the request has an empty body or no roomName
  if (!req.body || !req.body.roomName) {
    return res.status(400).send("Must include roomName argument.");
  }
  const roomName = req.body.roomName;
  // find or create a room with the given roomName
  findOrCreateRoom(roomName);
  // generate an Access Token for a participant in this room
  const token = getAccessToken(roomName);
  res.send({
    token: token,
  });
});

// Start the Express server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Express server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

If I send a curl request:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5002/join-room \
> -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
> --data '{"room_name": "1"}'
```

I get the same error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a dict. // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=style.css"
        type="text/css">
    <!-- We need to make sure this has a favicon so that the debugger does
         not by accident trigger a request to /favicon.ico which might
         change the application state. -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon"
        href="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=console.png">
    <script src="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=debugger.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var TRACEBACK = 3007471184,
          CONSOLE_MODE = false,
          EVALEX = true,
          EVALEX_TRUSTED = false,
          SECRET = "wVFYCZ8v9Z6Jk8Bi8NIM";
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #fff">
    <div class="debugger">
<h1>builtins.TypeError</h1>
<div class="detail">
  <p class="errormsg">TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a dict.</p>
</div>
<h2 class="traceback">Traceback <em>(most recent call last)</em></h2>
<div class="traceback">
  
  <ul><li><div class="frame" id="frame-3007471216">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">2309</em>,
      in <code class="function">__call__</code></h4>
  <div class="source"><pre class="line before"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">    </span>def __call__(self, environ, start_response):</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>&quot;&quot;&quot;The WSGI server calls the Flask application object as the</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>WSGI application. This calls :meth:`wsgi_app` which can be</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>wrapped to applying middleware.&quot;&quot;&quot;</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">        </span>return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span>def __repr__(self):</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>return '&lt;%s %r&gt;' % (</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>self.__class__.__name__,</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>self.name,</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-3007470576">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">2295</em>,
      in <code class="function">wsgi_app</code></h4>
  <div class="source"><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>try:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span>ctx.push()</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span>response = self.full_dispatch_request()</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>except Exception as e:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span>error = e</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">                </span>response = self.handle_exception(e)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>except:</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                </span>error = sys.exc_info()[1]</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                </span>raise</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>return response(environ, start_response)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>finally:</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-3007470928">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1741</em>,
      in <code class="function">handle_exception</code></h4>
  <div class="source"><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span># if we want to repropagate the exception, we can attempt to</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span># raise it with the whole traceback in case we can do that</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span># (the function was actually called from the except part)</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span># otherwise, we just raise the error again</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>if exc_value is e:</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">                </span>reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>else:</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                </span>raise e</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>self.log_exception((exc_type, exc_value, tb))</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>if handler is None:</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-3022875920">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">35</em>,
      in <code class="function">reraise</code></h4>
  <div class="source"><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">    </span>from io import StringIO</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">    </span>def reraise(tp, value, tb=None):</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>if value.__traceback__ is not tb:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>raise value.with_traceback(tb)</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">        </span>raise value</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span>implements_to_string = _identity</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span>else:</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span>text_type = unicode</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-3022876624">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">2292</em>,
      in <code class="function">wsgi_app</code></h4>
  <div class="source"><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>ctx = self.request_context(environ)</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>error = None</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>try:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>try:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span>ctx.push()</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">                </span>response = self.full_dispatch_request()</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>except Exception as e:</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                </span>error = e</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                </span>response = self.handle_exception(e)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>except:</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                </span>error = sys.exc_info()[1]</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-3007471120">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1816</em>,
      in <code class="function">full_dispatch_request</code></h4>
  <div class="source"><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>rv = self.preprocess_request()</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>if rv is None:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span>rv = self.dispatch_request()</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>except Exception as e:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">        </span>return self.finalize_request(rv)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span>def finalize_request(self, rv, from_error_handler=False):</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>&quot;&quot;&quot;Given the return value from a view function this finalizes</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>the request by converting it into a response and invoking the</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>postprocessing functions.  This is invoked for both normal</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-3005847728">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1831</em>,
      in <code class="function">finalize_request</code></h4>
  <div class="source"><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>with the `from_error_handler` flag.  If enabled, failures in</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>response processing will be logged and otherwise ignored.</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>:internal:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>&quot;&quot;&quot;</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">        </span>response = self.make_response(rv)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>try:</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>response = self.process_response(response)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>request_finished.send(self, response=response)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>except Exception:</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>if not from_error_handler:</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-3005847536">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1982</em>,
      in <code class="function">make_response</code></h4>
  <div class="source"><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                        </span>'{e}\nThe view function did not return a valid'</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                        </span>' response. The return type must be a string, tuple,'</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                        </span>' Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a'</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                        </span>' {rv.__class__.__name__}.'.format(e=e, rv=rv)</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                    </span>)</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">                    </span>reraise(TypeError, new_error, sys.exc_info()[2])</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span># prefer the status if it was provided</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>if status is not None:</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>if isinstance(status, (text_type, bytes, bytearray)):</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                </span>rv.status = status</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-3005847760">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">34</em>,
      in <code class="function">reraise</code></h4>
  <div class="source"><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">    </span>from inspect import getfullargspec as getargspec</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">    </span>from io import StringIO</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">    </span>def reraise(tp, value, tb=None):</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>if value.__traceback__ is not tb:</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">            </span>raise value.with_traceback(tb)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>raise value</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span>implements_to_string = _identity</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span>else:</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-3007470960">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1974</em>,
      in <code class="function">make_response</code></h4>
  <div class="source"><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span>status = headers = None</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>else:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span># evaluate a WSGI callable, or coerce a different response</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span># class to the correct type</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span>try:</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">                    </span>rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                </span>except TypeError as e:</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                    </span>new_error = TypeError(</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                        </span>'{e}\nThe view function did not return a valid'</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                        </span>' response. The return type must be a string, tuple,'</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                        </span>' Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a'</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-3005848240">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">921</em>,
      in <code class="function">force_type</code></h4>
  <div class="source"><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>&quot;&quot;&quot;</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>if not isinstance(response, BaseResponse):</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>if environ is None:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span>raise TypeError('cannot convert WSGI application into '</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                                </span>'response objects without an environ')</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">            </span>response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>response.__class__ = cls</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>return response</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span>@classmethod</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span>def from_app(cls, app, environ, buffered=False):</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-3005848016">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/test.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">923</em>,
      in <code class="function">run_wsgi_app</code></h4>
  <div class="source"><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>if exc_info is not None:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>reraise(*exc_info)</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>response[:] = [status, headers]</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>return buffer.append</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">    </span>app_rv = app(environ, start_response)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span>close_func = getattr(app_rv, 'close', None)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span>app_iter = iter(app_rv)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span># when buffering we emit the close call early and convert the</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span># application iterator into a regular list</pre></div>
</div>
</ul>
  <blockquote>TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a dict.</blockquote>
</div>

<div class="plain">
  <form action="/?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=paste" method="post">
    <p>
      <input type="hidden" name="language" value="pytb">
      This is the Copy/Paste friendly version of the traceback.  <span
      class="pastemessage">You can also paste this traceback into
      a <a href="https://gist.github.com/">gist</a>:
      <input type="submit" value="create paste"></span>
    </p>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="code" readonly>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py&quot;, line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py&quot;, line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py&quot;, line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py&quot;, line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py&quot;, line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py&quot;, line 1816, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py&quot;, line 1831, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py&quot;, line 1982, in make_response
    reraise(TypeError, new_error, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py&quot;, line 34, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py&quot;, line 1974, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py&quot;, line 921, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/test.py&quot;, line 923, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a dict.</textarea>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="explanation">
  The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application.  You can now
  look at the traceback which led to the error.  <span class="nojavascript">
  If you enable JavaScript you can also use additional features such as code
  execution (if the evalex feature is enabled), automatic pasting of the
  exceptions and much more.</span>
</div>
      <div class="footer">
        Brought to you by <strong class="arthur">DON'T PANIC</strong>, your
        friendly Werkzeug powered traceback interpreter.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pin-prompt">
      <div class="inner">
        <h3>Console Locked</h3>
        <p>
          The console is locked and needs to be unlocked by entering the PIN.
          You can find the PIN printed out on the standard output of your
          shell that runs the server.
        <form>
          <p>PIN:
            <input type=text name=pin size=14>
            <input type=submit name=btn value="Confirm Pin">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<!--

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1816, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1831, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in make_response
    reraise(TypeError, new_error, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1974, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 921, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 923, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a dict.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by re-creating the project from scratch directly on the Raspberry Pi.

Although I would love to know why it didn't 'just' transfer, I'm happy to have it working.